# Implement Json.NET in WCF Message Formatter

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I'm trying to replace the Json converter that is used by WCF with an open
source Json.NET (http://json.codeplex.com) mainly due the need to serialize
objects with circular references [DataContract(IsReference=true)] I tried 
to inject it in custom IDispatchMessageFormatter with no success. Has anyone
encounter in this kind of customization? Do you know where can I get a sample 
or reference to depend on?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Refer to [Supporting different data and serialization formats in WCF by Carlos Figueira](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Supporting-different-data-b0351c9a).

Comment: +1 Thats what got my dispatch message formatter going, Carlos seems to know what he is talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NETFx Json.NET MediaTypeFormatter](http://nuget.org/packages/netfx-WebApi.JsonNetFormatter) to swap the default DataContractJsonSerializer with Json.Net serializer. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827933/json-net-serializer-for-wcf-rest-services/9829508#9829508) for more info.

[This page](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/PreserveObjectReferences.html) talks about how to preserve references during serialization/deserialization in Json.Net